# How do I reuse the object in the map function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a typescript code that is being used repetitively. I would like to reuse the code by assigning them to a variable and using them. For instance, I have defined an arrow function in the map function to return an object and I would like to know the best possible way to reuse the object.

Full partial code:

```
            let options: kendo.ui.GridOptions = {
                dataSource: {
                    pageSize: 10,
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: (opts: kendo.data.DataSourceTransportReadOptions) => {
                            self.http.get("/api/AssetConfiguration").then((response) => {
                                let resources: any;
                                let activeAssetTab = response.data.filter(x => (x.active == true && x.assetTypeActive == true && x.assetSubTypeActive == true));
                                let inActiveAssetTab = response.data.filter(x => (x.active == true || x.assetTypeActive == true || x.assetSubTypeActive == true));
                                let selectedTab = active ? activeAssetTab : inActiveAssetTab;
                                let mappedObjects = (x) => {
                                    assetClassificationId: x.assetClassificationId,
                                    assetTypeName: x.assetTypeName,
                                    assetSubTypeName: x.assetSubTypeName,
                                    assetClassificationName: x.assetClassificationName,
                                    classificationHiddenFromUser: x.classificationHiddenFromUser
                                };

                                if (self.searchQuery) {
                                    if (active) {
                                        resources = activeAssetTab.filter(x =>
                                            ((x.searchText.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) > -1) == true))
                                            .map(x => {
                                                return {
                                                    assetClassificationId: x.assetClassificationId,
                                                    assetTypeName: x.assetTypeName,
                                                    assetSubTypeName: x.assetSubTypeName,
                                                    assetClassificationName: x.assetClassificationName,
                                                    classificationHiddenFromUser: x.classificationHiddenFromUser
                                                }
                                            });                                        
                                    } else {
                                        resources = inActiveAssetTab.filter(x =>
                                            ((x.searchText.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) > -1) == true))
                                            .map(x => {
                                                return {
                                                    assetClassificationId: x.assetClassificationId,
                                                    assetTypeName: x.assetTypeName,
                                                    assetSubTypeName: x.assetSubTypeName,
                                                    assetClassificationName: x.assetClassificationName,
                                                    classificationHiddenFromUser: x.classificationHiddenFromUser
                                                }
                                            });
                                    }          

                                } else {

                                    resources = selectedTab
                                        .map(x => {
                                        return {
                                            assetClassificationId: x.assetClassificationId,
                                            assetTypeName: x.assetTypeName,
                                            assetSubTypeName: x.assetSubTypeName,
                                            assetClassificationName: x.assetClassificationName,
                                            classificationHiddenFromUser: x.classificationHiddenFromUser
                                        };
                                    });
                                }
                                opts.success(resources);

                            });
                        }
                    }
                },
                columns: [
                    { field: 'assetTypeName', title: 'Asset Type', template: '<span ng-click="$ctrl.edit(#: assetClassificationId#);">#: assetTypeName #</span>' },
                    { field: 'assetSubTypeName', title: 'Asset Sub Type' },
                    { field: 'assetClassificationName', title: 'Asset Classification', template: '<span ng-if="#: classificationHiddenFromUser #">n/a</span><span ng-if="!#: classificationHiddenFromUser #">#: assetClassificationName #</span>' },
                    { field: 'assetClassificationId', title: 'Edit', template: '<a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-edit" ng-click="$ctrl.edit(#: assetClassificationId#);"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span>Edit</a>', width: "100px" }
                ]
            }
```

The code that i am looking to optimize is:

```
.map(x => {
                                                return {
                                                    assetClassificationId: x.assetClassificationId,
                                                    assetTypeName: x.assetTypeName,
                                                    assetSubTypeName: x.assetSubTypeName,
                                                    assetClassificationName: x.assetClassificationName,
                                                    classificationHiddenFromUser: x.classificationHiddenFromUser
                                                }
                                            })
```

How can I reuse the same object in the map function?

Comment: **What** object? The one being returned by the `map` callback? Why would you want to reuse it? (You'd end up with the same object in all of the resulting array's elements.) Some other object?

Comment: Yes the one returned by the map function. I want to reduce the lines of code hence i thought it is better to reuse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a function that returns your object and pass its reference to `.map`. See below for an example.

```
const myFunction = x => {
  return {
    assetClassificationId: x.assetClassificationId,
    assetTypeName: x.assetTypeName,
    assetSubTypeName: x.assetSubTypeName,
    assetClassificationName: x.assetClassificationName,
    classificationHiddenFromUser: x.classificationHiddenFromUser
  };
}



resources = activeAssetTab.filter(x =>
  ((x.searchText.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) > -1) == true))
    .map(myFunction);
```